# Calculating relaxation time

Tags: time, polymers

When  exploring the viscoelastic properties of glassy polymer like PMMA, there are usually two relaxation mechanism: alpha and beta.

Usually beta relaxation time varies with temperature following arrhenius equation:

$$t=t_0 \exp(E/RT) $$

I have only activation energy $E$ and temperature $T$.

How can I calculate relaxation time $t$?